# How can I do a "mouse out" effect in Java?

Tags: java, swing, mouseout, mouselistener

I'm trying to mouse over a JButton (javax.swing.JButton) and set the border color, Now I can get this to work I with a mouse move event on the button, I just need to mouse out and I can't seem to find a way to get a mouse out effect to work. Any ideas or methods that could help? Note: MouseExited does not work. At least in my instance.

Comment: Are you talking about a Swing GUI?

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: mouseExited should work. If it doesn't something is wrong - example code, please

Comment: Ah I got it, simple mistake I forgot to call mouselistener, i had mousemotionlistener but no mouselistner :o

Answer (score 0):

What about a "mouse over" on the buttons parent Component? Set a flag if the mouse is over the button and if it is over the parent (surrounding) panel *and* the flag is set, you have something like "mouse out".

Comment: no - mouseExited should work, no need to randomly distribute flags

Comment: @kleopatra - you're right - some code should help us identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mouseExisted method is the way to achieve this effect.  If you are having trouble with it, then it is a problem in your code, but you are going down the right path.

Comment: "Ah I got it, simple mistake I forgot to call mouselistener, i had mousemotionlistener but no mouselistner :o – **Dennis 20 hours ago**" :)